# TypeScript compiler annoyance when adding new members to inline objects after declaration

Tags: typescript

I have a large (2000-line) javascript file that I'm making my way through converting to typescript, and among the annoyance that I'm currently hitting, I see patterns like this:

```
var data = { some_property: some_value, another_property: some_other_value };
```

And then later:

```
$.ajax({
```

...

```
complete: function(cfg) {
    var result = JSON.parse(cfg.responseText);
    data.some_property = result.some_property; // This is fine.
    data.some_different_property = result.some_different_property; // error
});
```

And I get an error like: The property 'some_different_property' does not exist on value of type '{some_property: ..., another_property: ... }'.

While this is cool that it inferred the types from the values in the line from var data = {...}, it would be rather painful to hand-write all of the potential properties into data for all of the times this pattern is used, and it's a compile error.

**Is there some compiler flag / way to get the compiler to infer that data here also has some_different_property?: (inferred type from usage) instead of clogging up my error list?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an interface with optional parameters, and then specify that your variable matches that interface:

```
interface my_interface {
  some_property;    // type defaults to 'any'
  another_property: string;
  some_different_property?: number;
}
var data: my_interface = { some_property: 10, another_property: '' };
data.some_different_property = 99;
```

You can also do this inline, if this interface isn't reused:

```
var data2: { prop1; prop2; prop3? } = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };
data2.prop3 = "three";
```

Comment: This was the approach I ended up using - add the members optionally that I consumed out of the AJAX handlers.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't any compiler flag. However you can always type it to be any manually:

```
var data:any = { some_property: some_value, another_property: some_other_value };
```

Here you are telling the compiler that ignore what I am assigning to this variable, there can be other properties (potentially even called `some_propertIE`, i.e. the compiler cannot check any misspellings for you once you allow this).

Alternately you can split declaration / assignment to separate lines. In this case the type is inferred to be `any` by default. However making this your default pattern can result in effectively untyped code.

```
var data; // compiler infers it to by any 
data = { some_property: some_value, another_property: some_other_value }; // and you can assign anything
```